# Opencart 2.2 website width extending blank page to the right

Tags: opencart

I am using Opencart 2.2 with the default theme and the width of the category page is extending another extra 50% to the right showing a white space.This does not happen on other pages like the homepage or product pages. My website is ilandlo dot com. I will share codes whichever is  required as I am not sure which one would be preferable.
I have no idea why this is happening, if someone can help me find the solution, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The payment gateway images module is creating trouble and taking more width than parents . 
The owl-wrapper class element has width 1964px that is causing trouble. 
This might be due to some wrong configuration of slideshow module or there is a bug in module that's creating an element of width more than the page widths.

Comment: Gateway module exists just above your footer on that category page